# How to specify the mandatory courses in this training managment web applicaiton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am developing a training management web-based system using ASP.NET. This application will display the training record of each employee to the managment. In our company, we have three different types of courses and some courses of each type are mandatory coruses. My database design is as following:

```
       Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisionID
       Division Table: DivisionID, DivisionName
         Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
          Group Table: GroupID, GroupName.
Employee_Course Table: Username, CourseID
```

(The first attribute is the primary key in each table except for the last table which consists of two foreign keys)

I could be able to retrieve all the information and show them in a nice GridView. The problem now is how to determine the mandatory courses. I don't know what I should do. Should I change the above design of the database? Should I show these courses in different categories? Also, how will the admin determine whether this is a mandatory course or not?
BTY, later on I will need to come up with a query that shows how many employees finish the mandatory courses, so design should be applicable to this issue.

Comment: Are you actually asking how the admin will decide if a course is mandatory?

Comment: How to implement this in the system with the database.

Comment: Add another column in table "Course Table" name it as ISmandatory  and set it to 0 for Notmandatory  and 1 for mandatory

Comment: Are mandatory courses required for all employees, or do different jobs, divisions etc... have different required courses?

Answer (score 1):

If there are courses which are mandatory and some which are not then apparently you need to store this classification in the database. If a mandatory course is always mandatory for every employee then you could add a `IsMandatory` column to the course table otherwise you might have to come up with some other table which stores the relationship of which course is mandatory for which employee (or group of employees).

Also if you have three types of courses then it would make sense to store the type for each course as well.